# Assigning a lambda to a function pointer when using member variables in the lambda

Tags: c++11, lambda

I use a function pointer as parameter for a template function which is using it as functor. However, if I define the lambda as below by calling a member variable of the class, the compiler complains if I want to assign it to a function pointer.

How can I assign a lambda to a function pointer, if it uses a member variable?

> note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform
>   this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

```
  // works
  bool(*arm_check_fcn)(const int &) = [](const int &pt) {
    return pt.m_Part == 3;
  };

  // fails
  bool (*bgr_check_fcn)(const int &) = [this](const int &pt) {
    return _ModelData.GetBackground() == pt;
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

A function did not contain any data, so no storage is needed, only the pointer to the address where the function is located. As a function pointer simply points to the function, a lambda without stored parameters can bed converted to a function pointer.

If the lambda *object* is a function pointer and stored data, the data must be stored somewhere. And a function pointer can not point to data and a function. For that it is simply impossible to convert a lambda function with captured data to a function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, only a stateless lambda, with no capture at all, can be coerced to a function pointer. If you need to capture `this` (or anything else), you'll need to change the target function proto, make it templated:

```
template<class F> int f(F &&f);
```

or accept an `std::function` instead of a pointer:

```
int f(std::function<bool(int)> const &f);
```

<sup>Or any other function-object wrapper.</sup>

(I've changed the argument type to `int` from the const-ref in `std::function`'s parameter as it usually makes little to no sense to bind const lvalue refs to scalar types.)

Comment: A pity, so I used a classic class functor :/

Comment: @dgrat How can you assign the functor to a function pointer? The lambda is more or less syntactic sugar for manual functor definitions.

Comment: I mean instead of passing a function pointer as template argument, I decided to pass a functor.

Comment: @dgrat I would still use a lambda. It's more concise and IMHO captures the intent of being a function better than a functor. I think it is also more in line with current coding conventions.

Comment: @Jens What do you mean by 'functor'?

Comment: @bipll I was referring to whatever dgrat meant in his comment "so I used a classic class functor". It should be a class with `operator()`.

Comment: Anonymous closure, a.k.a. lambda, falls into this category, too. :)